# Sanitize Angular-Material html markup with Angular2 and beyond

Tags: angular-material, angular5, angular6, sanitization, html-sanitizing

I am trying to output following html markup via **property binding** (square bracket syntax).

```
<mat-list>
    <mat-list-item class="mat-list-item-word-wrap">
        <mat-icon mat-list-icon>check</mat-icon>
        <h4 mat-line>List title 1</h4>
        <p mat-line>Content of list item 1.</p>
    </mat-list-item>
    <mat-list-item class="mat-list-item-word-wrap">
        <mat-icon mat-list-icon>check</mat-icon>
        <h4 mat-line>List title 2</h4>
        <p mat-line>Content of list item 2.</p>
    </mat-list-item>
    <mat-list-item class="mat-list-item-word-wrap">
        <mat-icon mat-list-icon>check</mat-icon>
        <h4 mat-line>List title 3</h4>
        <p mat-line>Content of list item 3.</p>
    </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

For markup above see: https://material.angular.io/components/list/overview#lists-with-icons)

Output in Angular html template:

`<div [innerHTML]="sanitizeServersideHtml(HtmlFromAbove)"></div>`

Even I process the html via bypassSecurityTrustHtml() method the list does not show up as it should (https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypasssecuritytrusthtml
).

What puzzles me is the html output, which seems to be correct but the list does not show up correct.

**Take a look at following stackblitz I created for this question:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-sanitize

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

**----- Update 1 -----**

With getting html (or in my case angular material markup) we are highly flexible regarding the content we want to show. We can show an angular material list in one case and some other material components in another case. That is why we get html from the API for this prototype application.

Regarding the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-sanitize)

[image: Screenshot of stackblitz]

The green list (green rectangle number 1) is hard-coded and appears correct in the browser.

The red one is provided by the API. It is sanitized via bypassSecurityTrustHtml() and the html output looks correct (see red rectangle 2b) but it appears incorrect (see red rectangle 2c)

**So why is html rendered correct but does not appear correct?**

Comment: With this block of HTML tags, why don't you just put it in a separate component and then call it using the element selector?

Comment: This content should be dynamic, and it is provided by a database via REST API. So I think a separate component does not help, right? Actually I think the problem is the material markup from Angular Material. It looks like the markup is processed correct by the bypassSecurityTrustHtml() function. Nevertheless it is not rendered correct by the browser.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I have the same scenario.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn’t and therefore had to use plain html without material components. Seems using material components in this way is a very rare case.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

You have to inspect your first case (not sanitized)  and put the same classes that are in there.

So your new mat-list cant be classless, you have to do it in every inner element such as:

```
<mat-list class="mat-list" role="list"> // and so on with other elements
```